# How do I stop my paint method form repeating twice?

Tags: java, swing, paint

Here is the code for a dice game that I am working on that outputs the results to a window. The paint method repeats twice, which is not good for me because I want the dice to roll once and then move on to the next frame. Please someone help me with this problem. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dice extends JApplet {

public static int pause(int n)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(n);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return n;
}

public void Dice() {
    JApplet app = new Dice();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dice Game");
    frame.setBounds(30, 50, 1300, 650);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(app);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int width = getWidth();    
    int height = getHeight(); 

    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        Random generator= new Random();
        int number = generator.nextInt(6)+1;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRoundRect(550, 150, 200, 200, 50, 50);
        System.out.println("Test");
        if (number == 1) {              //Roll one
            num = 1;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(640, 240, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 2) {                //Roll two
            num = 2;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 3) {                //Roll three
            num = 3;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(640, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 4) {                //Roll four
            num = 4;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 5) {                //Roll five
            num = 5;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(640, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 6) {                //Roll six
            num = 6;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 290, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        }
    }
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.drawString("You rolled a " + num, 590, 100);
    pause(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The short answer is - you can't.  You don't control when painting occurs that is the domain of the `RepaintManager`.
- You should also NEVER call `Thread.sleep` within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread and especially not within any `paint` method
- You should avoid overriding `paint` and instead use `paintComponent`
- You should avoid extending from `JFrame` and instead use something like `JPanel`, which actually has a `paintComponent` method.
- Animation of this nature is best achieved by using a Swing `Timer`, which will allow to employee a pause which is maintained outside of the EDT, but is triggered again within in the EDT making it safer to perform painting and updates

Take a look at

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For more details about how painting works in Swing and how to achieve what you are trying to do

**Updated with working example**

[image: Snake Eyes]

Cause I'm lazy, I've utilised the Graphics 2D API to draw the dots.  I did this because many of the dots appear in the same locations for many of the numbers...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DiceRoller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DiceRoller();
    }

    public DiceRoller() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Die());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Die extends JPanel {

        private int number = 1;

        public Die() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    number = (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(220, 220);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawRoundRect(10, 10, width - 20, height - 20, 50, 50);

            List<Shape> dots = new ArrayList<>(6);

            if (number == 1 || number == 3 || number == 5) {
                int x = (width - 20) / 2;
                int y = (height - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
            }

            if (number == 2 || number == 3 || number == 4 || number == 5 || number == 6) {

                int x = ((width / 2) - 20) / 2;
                int y = ((height / 2) - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x + (width / 2), y + (height / 2), 20, 20));

            }

            if (number == 4 || number == 5 || number == 6) {

                int x = (width / 2) + (((width / 2) - 20) / 2);
                int y = ((height / 2) - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x - (width / 2), y + (height / 2), 20, 20));

            }

            if (number == 6) {

                int x = (((width / 2) - 20) / 2);
                int y = (height - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x + (width / 2), y, 20, 20));

            }

            for (Shape dot : dots) {
                g2d.fill(dot);
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks for adding that extra bit it was very helpful. I really appreciate it.