# JFrame shows up grey, blank

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem where my frame shows up as grey, but then after a few seconds it displays the image as my for loop is finishing. I need to make it so that it displays the image correctly once it opens in order to show the loop. Here is my entire code, sorry about the length:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public void MainFrame() {
        setTitle("Game");
        setSize(1300, 650);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Dice diceObject = new Dice();
        add(diceObject);
    }
}
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Dice extends JPanel {

 public static int pause(int n)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(n);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return n;
    }

public void Dice() {
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int width = getWidth();    
    int height = getHeight(); 

    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        Random generator= new Random();
        int number = generator.nextInt(6)+1;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRoundRect(550, 150, 200, 200, 50, 50);
        System.out.println("Test");
        if (number == 1) {                  //Roll one
            num = 1;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(640, 240, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 2) {                //Roll two
            num = 2;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 3) {                //Roll three
            num = 3;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(640, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 4) {                //Roll four
            num = 4;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 5) {                //Roll five
            num = 5;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(640, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        } if (number == 6) {                //Roll six
            num = 6;
            g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
            g.fillOval(590, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(590, 290, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 190, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 240, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(690, 290, 20, 20);
            pause(100);
        }
    }
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.drawString("You rolled a " + num, 590, 100);
    pause(1000);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Didn't we already have this conversation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033199/how-do-i-stop-my-paint-method-form-repeating-twice)

Comment: Agreed with @MadProgrammer...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah I know but I tried another method any this one seems like it would work a lot better this way if I could get it to work.

Comment: It won't, it just won't this is simply not how painting works in Swing.  You'd have an easier time getting an elephant to fly using a single feather...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is the fact that you are setting the frame visible BEFORE you add anything to it...

Instead, try calling `setVisible` last

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public void MainFrame() {
        setTitle("Game");
        setSize(1300, 650);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Dice diceObject = new Dice();
        add(diceObject);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You should also avoid extending directly from `JFrame` as you're not adding any new functionality to the class and need to take into consideration [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and ensure you are starting the main UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The rest of your problems relate to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033199/how-do-i-stop-my-paint-method-form-repeating-twice)

**Updated with working example**

[image: Snake Eyes]

Cause I'm lazy, I've utilised the Graphics 2D API to draw the dots.  I did this because many of the dots appear in the same locations for many of the numbers...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DiceRoller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DiceRoller();
    }

    public DiceRoller() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Die());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Die extends JPanel {

        private int number = 1;

        public Die() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    number = (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(220, 220);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawRoundRect(10, 10, width - 20, height - 20, 50, 50);

            List<Shape> dots = new ArrayList<>(6);

            if (number == 1 || number == 3 || number == 5) {
                int x = (width - 20) / 2;
                int y = (height - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
            }

            if (number == 2 || number == 3 || number == 4 || number == 5 || number == 6) {

                int x = ((width / 2) - 20) / 2;
                int y = ((height / 2) - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x + (width / 2), y + (height / 2), 20, 20));

            }

            if (number == 4 || number == 5 || number == 6) {

                int x = (width / 2) + (((width / 2) - 20) / 2);
                int y = ((height / 2) - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x - (width / 2), y + (height / 2), 20, 20));

            }

            if (number == 6) {

                int x = (((width / 2) - 20) / 2);
                int y = (height - 20) / 2;
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 20, 20));
                dots.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x + (width / 2), y, 20, 20));

            }

            for (Shape dot : dots) {
                g2d.fill(dot);
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```